# When react perform componentDidMount and componentWillUnmount

Tags: reactjs

I played with React for several years, still confused with mount/unmount mechanism in some case.

Since mount/unmount is the place to perform side effect, I do not want them to be invoked randomly. So I need to figure out how they work. As far as I can understand currently, when the virtual dom do not present in real dom, it tend to be unmounted. However, it seems not the whole story, and I can not reason it about

```
function TestMount(props) {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("componentDidMount", props.name);
    return () => {
      console.log("componentWillUnount", props.name);
    };
  }, []);
  return <h1>Test content {" " + JSON.stringify(props.name)}</h1>;
}

function Update({ click }) {
  return <button onClick={click}>Update</button>;
}

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const Component = name => <TestMount name={name} />;
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{count}</h1>
      <Component name="one" />
      {Component("two")}
      <Update click={() => setCount(x => x + 1)} />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Component One is remount overtime the app render while Component two not?Why this happen?

Comment: Because `{name: 'one'} !== {name: 'one'}`, but `'two' === 'two'`

Comment: @zerkms can not see how it related to mount mechanism in react

Comment: @zerkms What is really relevant is `(()=>'one')!==(()=>'one')`,but `'two'==='two'`

Comment: I'm not sure why you think so, you have `{name: 'one'}` props, and I don't see where you have an anonymous function `() => 'one'`

Comment: @zerkms `()=>'one'` is actually legal react Component, another `()=>'one'` is an **another** react Component if have different identity. If different Components are initialized to create the element, react will unmount the first Component and remount the second Component, instead of update the "same" one

Comment: Not sure how it's relevant to your question. You have `{name: 'one'}` props in the code you posted (in this expression: `<Component name="one" />`). I'm not sure I see `()=>'one'` anywhere in your code. What is relevant is that you **actually pass** `{name: 'one'}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The key to such issue is the difference between the React Component and React element, put shortly `React` is smart with `element` not `Component`

#### Component vs element

Component is the template used to create element using `<>` operation. In my prospective, `<>` is pretty much like `new` operator in OOP world.

#### How React perform update between renders

Every time the `render` method(or functional component) is invoked. The new element is created using `<>`, however, `React` is smart enough to tell the element created between renders are actually the same one, i.e. it had been created before and can be reused **as long as the element is created by the same Component**

#### How about different Component

However when the identity of the Component using to generate element changes(Even if the Components look same), React believes something new come though, so it remove(unmount) the previous element and add(mount) the new one. Thus `componentDidMount` or `componentWillUnmount` is invoked.

#### How is confusing

Think we got a `Component` and when we generate `element` using `<Component />` react can tell the same elements because they are generated by the same `Component`
However, `HOCComponent=()=><Component />; element= <HOCComponent />`, every time `element` is generated, it used a different `Component`. it is actually a HOC constructed dynamically. Because the HOC is created dynamically inside render function, it can be confusing on the first glance.

#### Is that true

I never found any offical document about the idea above.However the code below is enough to prove

```
function TestMount(props) {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("componentDidMount", props.name);
    return () => {
      console.log("componentWillUnount", props.name);
    };
  }, []);
  return <h1>Test content {" " + JSON.stringify(props.name)}</h1>;
}

function Update({ click }) {
  return <button onClick={click}>Update</button>;
}

let _Component;
function cacheComponent(C) {
  if (C && !_Component) {
    _Component = C;
  }
  return _Component || null;
}

const CacheComponent2 = once(({ name }) => <TestMount name={name} />, []);

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  // can be used as a HOC of TestMount or a plain function returnnung a react element
  const Component = name => <TestMount name={name} />;
  const CacheComponent1 = cacheComponent(Component);
  const CacheComponent3 = useCallback(
    ({ name }) => <TestMount name={name} />,
    []
  );

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{count}</h1>
      {/* used as HOC */}
      <Component name="one" />
      {/* used as function returnning the element */}
      {Component("two")}
      <CacheComponent1 name="three" />
      <CacheComponent2 name="four" />
      <CacheComponent3 name="five" />
      <Update click={() => setCount(x => x + 1)} />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit react-unmount-case]

Also the code above provide three different ways to avoid the undesired mount/unmount. All the solutions are cache the identity of the HOC somehow

Answer (score 5):

`Component` is a new function each time `App` is rendered, so `<Component name="one" />` is remounted each time too, they are considered different components.

The result of `Component("two")` call is `<TestMount name={"two"} />`, `TestMount` stays the same each time `App` is rendered, so it's not remounted.

`Component` is invalid component for what it's used for, to pass `name` string as `name` prop to `TestMount` component because `name` parameter is not a string but props object when `Component` is used like `<Component name="one" />`. `name => <TestMount name={name} />` is *render function*, it's preferable to name it accordingly like `renderTestMount` for clarity because components aren't supposed to be called directly like `Component("two")`.

In case a function is supposed be used as component or render function interchangeably, the signature should be changed to `({ name }) => <TestMount name={name} />`.

The expected behaviour could be achieved for `<Component name="one" />` by memoizing `Component`:

```
const Component = useCallback(({ name }) => <TestMount name={name} />, []);
```

But since `Component` doesn't depend on `App` scope, a correct way is to define it outside:

```
const Component = ({ name }) => <TestMount name={name} />;

function App() {...}
```

For instance, this is the reason React Router `Route` has separate `component` and `render` props for a component and [render function](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func). This allows to prevent unnecessary remounts for route components that need to be defined dynamically in current scope.

Comment: Thank for your answer, the difference between `render` and `component` in `react-router` make sense to me all of a sudden. The key of the issue it that `React` is good at `element` not `Component`, just notice that you can not `useCallback` outside `App` due to hook limitation, `lodash.once` should be what you mean

Comment: You're welcome. You don't need useCallback outside App, Component already stays the same between renders, it's regular component this way.

Comment: "Component is invalid component because it accepts name as an argument instead of props" --- how so? It's a function and it may have arguments with any name, be it `name` or `foo`

Comment: @zerkms A param can have any name but that that it's `name` suggests that it's expected to receive name string as an arg like `Component("two")`, while it receives props object when its used as a component.

Comment: @estus it does not make it **invalid**: 1) The name of the argument changes nothing 2) It's okay to pass an object as a react component property. I admit though that I misinterpret the *invalid* term.

Comment: @zerkms `<Component name="one" />` and `{Component("two")}` aren't interchangeable. It's invalid for OP's intention, to make `TestMount` receive a string as `name` prop. I'll update the answer to make myself clear.

Comment: @estus right. It originally looked that it's invalid from the react library perspective, sorry.